# How to set up ArcGIS Server 10.1 test environment on Mac laptop with VMware?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, mac, virtual-machine

In my production environment I have ArcGIS Server 10.0 Enterprise, ArcSDE 9.3, and ArcIMS. I want to shut down ArcIMS as soon as possible for obvious reasons, and upgrade ArcSDE 9.3 to 10.1 and ArcGIS for Server 10.0 to 10.1. As I am new to ArcGIS for Server 10.1, I would like to set up a test environment just to get to know the software architecture but will not be able to do this on my network at work. I would therefore like to do this on my laptop with VMware.

Could anyone guide me as to how I should do this on my Mac with VMware?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Read through installation guide for installing ArcGIS Server on the chosen OS. Here is the [link](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/install-guides/arcgis-server/10.1/index.html#/Installing_ArcGIS_10_1_SP1_for_Server/01nm0000002m000000/) for Windows. Go for ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 directly, no need to install 10.1 first since 10.1 SP1 is anyway a full installation (not like you did in 10.0 and earlier).
2. Make sure you have met the [system requirements](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.1/index.html#//015100000072000000). Since you have a VMWare, make sure to choose a supported OS for your machine. I usually go for Win7 or Win2008R2 Server when setting up a sandbox machine.
3. Download the ArcGIS Server media from [Esri Customer Care Portal](https://customers.esri.com/) if you don't have it yet. You will need your account number to log in.
4. If you will work with VMWare in production, consider reading through a couple of documents on implementing ArcGIS Server in the VMWare environment. [Here](https://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/products/vsphere/VMware-HA-Deployment-Guide-Esri-ArcGIS.pdf) and [here](http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/arcgis-server-virtualization.pdf).

Just in case you might consider other alternatives, if you want to get access to the ArcGIS Server machine ready-to-use you might consider taking a look at the [Esri Amazon images](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00rq0000005w000000) which you can spin in a couple of minutes. It is inexpensive options and you can save some time on preparing the machines, however you would need to have Internet access to work with machines and set up own Amazon account for billing. Here is the free [60 min training](http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?fa=catalog.webCourseDetail&courseID=1957) from Esri.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The VMWare test environment will not be used for production. I just want to set up an environment which I can run from one laptop - my macbook pro. Can I install everything on the one machine? or should I virtualize 2 machines?

Comment: You can definitely install ArcGIS Server just on one machine only on a supported OS. There is no need to have multiple physical or virtual machines available.

Answer (score 2):

When creating the virtual machine I would chose bridging mode for the network interface card. This way, when you install the test operating system it will get an IP from the same newtork subnet -- like having another computer on your lan. (e.g. if you currently have the ip 192.168.1.33 the guest will get an ip like 192.168.1.xx)

To avoid any possible future  problems.
From the guest operating system you should either configure the network card with static ip address (like you did with your host computer -- in this case your Mac) or if you have a dhcp server you should configure it so that it assigns the same ip to your test virtual computer when you turn it on. This way, your test server will always have the same ip on your LAN.

If you want more detailed specifics please ask.
Creating a guest operating system should be super easy with Vmware but also other virtualization systems. Just follow from here on the ESRI documentation for installing the Arcgis server.

That's about it.